# ViewController .viewDidLoad not called when opening from push notification

Tags: ios, swift

In my storyboard i have a `HomeViewNavigationController` whose root view controller is `HomeViewController`. I have some other view controllers and a view controller called `PushViewController`. Like so:

```
HomeViewNavigationController ---(root view)--> HomeViewController --> AViewController --> BViewController --> PushViewController
```

When my app is not running and i receive a push and i want to open the `HomeViewController` i just initialize the `HomeViewNavigationController` and set it as my `rootViewController` like so:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let homeViewNav = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewNavController") as? UINavigationController

    self.window?.rootViewController = homeViewNav
    completionHandler()
}
```

But i would like to open `PushViewController` and have the back button link to `HomeViewController`. So i do this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let homeViewNav = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewNavController") as? UINavigationController

    let pushView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PushViewController") as! PushViewController
    homeViewNav.pushViewController(pushView, animated: true)

    self.window?.rootViewController = homeViewNav
    completionHandler()
}
```

Problem is that my `.ViewDidLoad` function in `HomeViewController` is never called but my `.viewWillDisappear` function is called. as a result when i try to dispose of a variable in `.viewWillDisappear` that was never initialized in `.viewDidLoad`, my app crashes.

How do i push `pushViewController` on the stack but ensure that `HomeViewController` is properly initialized

FYI: This seems to happen some times, not all the time. Sometimes the `.viewDidLoad` function is called and everything works fine. Seems like a race condition.

Comment: Show pic of storyboard so we can see which ViewControllers are associated with which, please.

Comment: use main thread help you out

Comment: @impression7vx company code of unreleased app. I can't really do that. Maybe i will try to reproduce it on a small project. But the storyboard is very much like described. `HomeViewNavigationController ---(root view)--> HomeViewController --> AViewController --> BViewController --> PushViewController
` . Does everything else look fine?

Comment: @MAbubakerMajeed hmmm. That might fix it. I will test it out. Problem with race conditions is that if it doesn't happen for a while, i can't really tell if the problem was fixed or if it just happened yet. But does everything else look fine?